# limit multiple arguments to specific set of strings each

Tags: python

I would like to restrict multiple arguments to different sets of strings. Following the your suggestions in order to make my question more clear, this is my code which is intended to become a wrapper for a API:

```
import requests

class Judikatur():
    def __init__(self,
                 category: str,
                 published="Undefined",
                 entscheidungstexte=True,
                 rechtssaetze=True,
                 VfghRequestEntscheidungsart="Undefined",
                 VwghRequestEntscheidungsart="Undefined",
                 BvwgRequestEntscheidungsart="Undefined",
                 LvwgRequestEntscheidungsart="Undefined",
                 GbkRequestEntscheidungsart="Undefined",
                 GbkKommission="Undefined",
                 GbkSenat="Undefined",
                 GbkDiskriminierungsgrund="Undefined",
                 DskRequestEntscheidungsart="Undefined",
                 DskBehoerde="Undefined",
                 PvakBehoerde="Undefined",
                 LvwgBundesland="Undefined"):
```

I then procede to check whether the provided strings are accepted by the API.

```
        if category not in ["Justiz", "Vfgh", "Vwgh", "Bvwg", "Lvwg", "Gbk", "Dsk", "Dok", "Pvak"]:
            raise ValueError('Please provide a valid category. Valid categories are:\n\
                "Justiz" for "Gerichtsentscheidungen";\n\
                "Vfgh" for "Entscheidungen des Verfassungsgerichtshofs";\n\
                "Vwgh" for "Entscheidungen des Verwaltungsgerichtshofs";\n\
                "Bvwg" for "Entscheidungen des Bundesverwaltungsgerichts";\n\
                "Lvwg" for "Entscheidungen der Landesverwaltungsgerichte";\n\
                "Gbk" for "Entscheidungen der Gleichbehandlungskommission";\n\
                "Dsk" for "Entscheidungen der Datenschutzbehörde";\n\
                "Dok" for "Entscheidungen der Disziplinarkommission";\n\
                "Pvak" for "Personalvertretungsaufsichtsbehörde".')

        if published not in ["Undefined", "EinerWoche", "ZweiWochen", "EinemMonat", "DreiMonaten", "SechsMonaten", "EinemJahr"]:
            raise ValueError(
                'Please provide a valid time since publication. The API accepts "Undefined", "EinerWoche", "ZweiWochen", "EinemMonat", "DreiMonaten", "SechsMonaten" or "EinemJahr".')

        if VfghRequestEntscheidungsart not in ["Undefined", "Beschluss", "Erkenntnis", "Vergleich"]:
            raise ValueError(
                'Please provide a valid argument for "VfghRequestEntscheidungsart". The API accepts "Undefined", "Beschluss", "Erkenntnis" or "Vergleich".')

        if VwghRequestEntscheidungsart not in ["Undefined", "Beschluss", "Erkenntnis", "BeschlussVS", "ErkenntnisVS"]:
            raise ValueError(
                'Please provide a valid argument for "VwghRequestEntscheidungsart". The API accepts "Undefined", "Beschluss", "Erkenntnis", "BeschlussVS" or "ErkenntnisVS".')

        if BvwgRequestEntscheidungsart not in ["Undefined", "Beschluss", "Erkenntnis"]:
            raise ValueError(
                'Please provide a valid argument for "BvwgRequestEntscheidungsart". The API accepts "Undefined", "Beschluss" or "Erkenntnis".')

        if LvwgRequestEntscheidungsart not in ["Undefined", "Beschluss", "Erkenntnis", "Bescheid"]:
            raise ValueError(
                'Please provide a valid argument for "LvwgRequestEntscheidungsart". The API accepts "Undefined", "Beschluss", "Erkenntnis" or "Bescheid".')

        # etc.
pass
```

Many arguments take similar strings, but no set of accepted strings is identical.

Is there a possibility to reduce the above code which checks if the provided strings are accepted by the API?

Comment: More information is needed. Provide an example or explain what you need more briefly.

Comment: One thing is, passing 20 parameters to a function is a bad sign of designing the code. Consider creating a special data structure and maybe work with json/yaml/csv etc.

Comment: you are checking same if condition with different values instaed you can define `lambda` expression or function

Comment: As suggested I provided the concrete example to make my question more clear.

Comment: You should be using something like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) or [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to do this kind of validation.

Answer (score 1):

[Enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) are the usual way to define a fixed set of possible values. Your title asks for strings and the question shows numbers, but enums can be expressed as either.

As you see in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), you can specify your own number values

```
class Mood(Enum):
    FUNKY = 1
    HAPPY = 3
```

and likewise string names. Then, `member.value` and `member.name` let you access these.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(x):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        list = []
        for _ in range(len(x)):
            list.append(count+1)
            count += 1
        if not x[i][0] in list:
            raise ValueError()
    pass
```

list = [[1], [4], [7]]
func(list)